# Push permalink from JavaScript into an 'href' attribute

Tags: javascript, push, href, soundcloud, permalinks

So I have a function that retrieves a user's SoundCloud permalink. I want it to so that onclick() of a seperate button it pushes this permalink into an href attribute in the HTML document. Any suggestions? (I simplified things by just putting a link to SoundCloud but in my app this link will actually change on every click of the 'Load' button). Thanks

HTML

```
<a href="" target="_blank"> SoundCloud </a>

<a onclick="loadPerma();">Load</a>
```

JavaScript (example)

```
var permalink = "www.soundcloud.com"

function loadPerma(){

   var object = {perma: permalink};
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking; sounds as if you don’t even know the basics of how you access HTML elements in JavaScript …? If that is the case, please go do some proper research on such elementary things first.

Comment: I know `document.getElementById` but just wanted some suggestions on how to go about this. I haven't coded in ages and came back to a project that I was working on and was just hoping for some guidance. Thought this would be quite straigh forward actually..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is the use of `var object = {perma: permalink};`

You can use [**setAttribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set the `href` attribute on click of `load`

```
var permalink = "www.soundcloud.com"
function loadPerma(){
document.getElementById('abc').setAttribute('href',permalink)
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zrkvr1sx/)

Comment: setAttrbiute can be problematic - a simple `document.getElementById('abc').href = permalink;` does the job as well, sometimes even better.

Comment: @CBroe Initially i tried that way but it didnt set href. I retried it [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zrkvr1sx/1/). You can check by inspecting element,

Comment: Yes it does. But you are setting the wrong URL - `www.soundcloud.com` is a _relative_ URL, pointing to a file/folder of that name under the current path. You need to use an absolute URL such as `http://www.soundcloud.com` of course. https://jsfiddle.net/zrkvr1sx/2/